# strange behavior of php referral function

Tags: php, mysql

I have a referral script this script

```
<?php
ob_start();
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'dbnamehere');
define('DB_USER', 'dbuserhere');
define('DB_PASS', 'dbpasshere');
mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
$id = $_REQUEST['id']; 
$uid = $_REQUEST['uid']; 
$oid = $_REQUEST['oid']; // completed offer or payment method
$new = $_REQUEST['new']; 
$total = $_REQUEST['total'];
$sig = $_REQUEST['sig'];
$timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

// Secrete Key
$key = 'e5870b6ab402d790a5d6bd1cefaee7c4';

// Compare results
$hash = md5($id.':'.$new.':'.$uid.':'.$key);

// Output results
if ($sig == $hash) {

        print "1\n";


//Users point update query here
 $users = mysql_query("SELECT points FROM users WHERE id=".$uid);
 $rows = mysql_fetch_array($users);
 $user_points = $rows['points'];
 $query1 = mysql_query("update users set points=($user_points+$new/2) where id=$uid ");


//Updating referral coins 
        $query2 = "select points, referral_id from users where referral_id=".$uid;  
        $user_rows = mysql_query($query2);
        $all=mysql_fetch_array($user_rows,MYSQL_BOTH);
        if($all['referral_id'] != 0){
             echo $referal_points = intval((25/100) * $new);
             $update_referral_points = "update users set points = points + '$referal_points' WHERE id = ".$all['referral_id'];
             mysql_query($update_referral_points);

                    }

        } else {
            print "0\n";
}
?>
```

**When i run this script database rows not updating see example below**

```
    id | points | referral_id
    ---|--------|--------
    1  | 1000   | 2
    2  | 2000   | 0
    3  | 1000   | 2
```

**For Example:**

if $uid = 1 & $new = 100
Or 
$uid = 3 & $new = 100
we need to award $new= (100*25)/100 = +25 to id=2 in id = 2 because id = 1 & 3 has referral_id = 2

```
    id | points | referral_id
    ---|--------|--------
    1  | 1100   | 2
    2  | 2000   | 0
    3  | 1100   | 2
```

**After Success i am expecting results like this**

```
    id | points | referral_id
    ---|--------|--------
    1  | 1100   | 2
    2  | 2025   | 0
    3  | 1100   | 2
```

The script successfully  print "1\n"; and query1 also working without query2 and when i run with query2 it stop updating database and even stop print "1\n";

Comment: You need to tell us what went wrong. Did you get an error? Did the row not update?

Comment: I'm running it with cron job the whole script expect (part of code ) i shared is working but when i put this code database not gonna get or store values, in short yes row not updated

Comment: any suggestions ?

Comment: What are the values of `$uid` and `$new` being passed in `$_REQUEST` in this example?

Comment: @retrospectacus please review question i have added example init

Comment: It looks like this code should definitely print "1" or "0" - if not printing either, it is probably a syntax error and you should see it reported in the webserver log.

Comment: yeah something wrong in syntex but i am not sure where, let me check and back to you shortly

Answer (score 2):

In your update query, the where clause should be; WHERE id = ".$all['referral_id']
because the referral_id is the id of the referrer.

Your code may be susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: I am finding it difficult to believe you have read anything I wrote

Comment: i try by replacing user_id with id as you told but it's not working

Comment: You need to better explain what you are trying to do and what is happening - show an example with data before and after your script runs, including the actual result and the desired result

Comment: i have added an example in question for better understanding, hope it's much clear now